# Login page doesn't work fully it works when segue connected but doesn't check if user is registered or not

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

Login page doesn't really check for if user is stored in core data and will just go ahead with the segue. It should login only if user is registered in core data else will input error and to go register but register seems to work correctly tho I followed some guides online

I have attached the code please check and give me some suggestion to achieve my task

LoginVC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    var credits = 200.0
    
    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        fetchData()
    }

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
        for acc in userList {
            if acc.username == username.text && acc.password == password.text {
                    currentUser = username.text!
                    try! context.save()
                //performSegue(withIdentifier: "DisplayShop1", sender: nil)
                let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                
                let next = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DisplayShop1") as! ListingShopVC
                next.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
            }
            else if username.text != acc.username || password.text != acc.password || password.text == "" || username.text == "" {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter the correct credentials", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
                
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "hellothere" {
            let ve = segue.destination as! ListingShopVC
            ve.creditsss = credits
        }
        }
        func fetchData(){
        userList = try! context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
       }
      }
```

RegisterVC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RegisterVC: UIViewController {
    
    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var userList: String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cpassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {
        if username.text != ""{
        if password.text != "" {
        if password.text == cpassword.text {
                    let newu = User(context: context)
                    newu.username = username.text
                    newu.password = password.text
                    newu.credit = 200.0
                    
                    try! context.save()
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
                else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter values correctly", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)*/
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, check that you haven't created a segue from the login button in your storyboard to the logged in scene; It will trigger regardless of any code you have in the `@IBAction`.  Once you have ruled that out, set a breakpoint in `login` and step through your code to see what is happening

Comment: how you have declared userList in LoginVC ?

Comment: so far ive only used userList in the for loop

Comment: and the fetch func below